# Docker container stuck in a build loop

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i'm facing a problem with docker. I'm working on a multi-container Docker application using a node server, a postgreSQL database and adminer. When i run the command `docker-compose up` everything looks to work fine until i encounter a loop situation :

```
serveur_1  | yarn install v1.22.4
serveur_1  | [1/4] Resolving packages...
serveur_1  | success Already up-to-date.
serveur_1  | Done in 0.86s.
serveur_1  | yarn run v1.22.4
serveur_1  | $ ts-node-dev --inspect=0.0.0.0:5858 --respawn --transpileOnly -- 
detectOpenHandles ./app/index.ts
serveur_1  | Usage: ts-node-dev [options] script [arguments]
serveur_1  |
serveur_1  | error Command failed with exit code 1.
serveur_1  | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this 
command.
devops_serveur_1 exited with code 1
serveur_1  | yarn install v1.22.4
serveur_1  | [1/4] Resolving packages...
serveur_1  | success Already up-to-date.
serveur_1  | Done in 0.83s.
serveur_1  | yarn run v1.22.4
serveur_1  | $ ts-node-dev --inspect=0.0.0.0:5858 --respawn --transpileOnly -- 
detectOpenHandles ./app/index.ts
serveur_1  | Usage: ts-node-dev [options] script [arguments]
serveur_1  |
serveur_1  | error Command failed with exit code 1.
serveur_1  | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this 
command.
devops_serveur_1 exited with code 1
serveur_1  | yarn install v1.22.4
serveur_1  | [1/4] Resolving packages...
serveur_1  | success Already up-to-date.
serveur_1  | Done in 0.84s.
serveur_1  | yarn run v1.22.4
serveur_1  | $ ts-node-dev --inspect=0.0.0.0:5858 --respawn --transpileOnly -- 
detectOpenHandles ./app/index.ts
serveur_1  | Usage: ts-node-dev [options] script [arguments]
serveur_1  |
serveur_1  | error Command failed with exit code 1.
serveur_1  | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this 
command.
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      POSTGRES_USER: $DB_USERNAME
      POSTGRES_DB: $DB_NAME
    networks:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  serveur:
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: "node:12.16.3"
    working_dir: /app
    command: bash -c "yarn && yarn dev"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "${API_PORT:-5000}:${API_PORT:-5000}"
    volumes:
      - ./serveur:/app
    environment:
      PORT: $API_PORT
      DB_PORT: $DB_PORT
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      DB_USERNAME: $DB_USERNAME
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      JWTSECRET: $JWTSECRET
    networks:
      - database
      - front

  admin:
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - database
    ports:
      - "${ADMINER_PORT:-5050}:8080"

  # client:
  #   image: "node:12.16.3"
  #   working_dir: /app
  #   command: bash -c "yarn && yarn start"
  #   restart: always
  #   stdin_open: true
  #   ports:
  #     - "${FRONT_PORT:-3000}:3000"
  #   environment:
  #     REACT_APP_API_URL: http://localhost:${API_PORT:-5000}
  #   depends_on:
  #     - serveur
  #   volumes:
  #     - ./client:/app
  #   networks:
  #     - front

networks:
  database:
  front:
```

It seem to be a problem with the volumes but i'm not sure about that, what would be the best approch for solving this issue ?

Any help would be much appreciated !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually you'd build your application source code into a Docker _image_: write a Dockerfile, `COPY` the source code in, `RUN yarn install` once in the Dockerfile, and do not specify `working_dir:`, `command:`, or `volumes:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  Docker's [Build and run your image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) tutorial goes through this process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are here because you think your docker settings were faulty or something wrong with your code and you are using `ts-node-dev` package. The problem might be in how you are setting options on `ts-node-dev`. They change `--transpileOnly` option to `--transpile-only`. took me 3 hours to figure this out. The error message didn't help.

```
➜ npm run dev        

> ts-node-dev --inspect=0.0.0.0 --respawn --transpileOnly startup.ts <-- ERROR HERE. SHOULD BE --transpile-only

ts-node-dev: no script to run provided
Usage: ts-node-dev [options] script [arguments]

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ggpo-server@1.0.0 dev: `ts-node-dev --inspect=0.0.0.0 --respawn --transpileOnly startup.ts`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ggpo-server@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2021-07-03T23_59_58_287Z-debug.log
```

For reference: https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev/issues/223